# Find greatest value of subset of array

Tags: c#

I need some C# help.  I have an array of integers with 5 values:

```
Int[] arrayValues = { 10, 8, 6, 5, 3 };
```

I need to find the greatest value for any combination of three values (10 combination possibilities) and then rearrange the values so that the 3 values that have the greatest sum are in the last 3 positions.

Comment: You need to do more than just post your requirements as a question. Tell us some of the things you've tried; give us some evidence that you've thought about this question and how best to solve it. Preferably, show us a sample of code that doesn't work properly. But most importantly, *ask an actual question*.

Comment: found, 10 is greatest :)

Comment: SO turning into a "please do my homework" site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is:

1. Sort the array in ascending order
2. Last 3 elements are the 3 largest elements in the array i.e. the combination with the largest sum
3. Find the sum of the largest elements
4. Store the non largest elements in the result array, thus maintaining the original order.
5. Append the largest elements at the end of the result array.

The code is something like this (it can be optimized),

```
int[] orginalArray = { 10, 8, 6, 5, 3 };
int[] copyArray = new int[orginalArray.Length];
int[] resultArray = new int[orginalArray.Length];

// Make a copy of the orginal array
Array.Copy(orginalArray,0, copyArray, 0,orginalArray.Length);

// Sort the copied array in ascendng order (last 3 elements are the largest 3 elements)
Array.Sort(copyArray);

// Array to store the largest elements
int[] largest = new int[3];

for (int i = copyArray.Length - 3, j = 0; i < copyArray.Length; i++, j++)
{
    largest[j] = copyArray[i];
}

// Sum of the largest elements
int largestSum = largest.Sum();

// Copy the non largest elements to the result array (in the original order)
for (int i = 0, j=0; i < orginalArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (!largest.Contains(orginalArray[i]))
    {
        resultArray[j++] = orginalArray[i];
    }
}

// Copy the largest elements to the last 3 positions
for(int i=largest.Length - 1, j=0;i<resultArray.Length;i++, j++)
{
    resultArray[i] = largest[j];
}

// Result - resultArray[] : 5 3 6 8 10
// Largest sum combination - largest[]: 6 8 10
// Sum of largest combination - largestSum: 24
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just the array sorted in ascending order.

```
arrayValues.sort()
```

should work and list the numbers in the ascending order

Comment: I think you mean `Array.Sort(arrayValues);`

Comment: @Cody: Yeah Sorry, I use IEnumerable most of the time and I tend to get Array.sort() and IEnumerable.sort() mixed up

Comment: There is neither an `Array.sort` nor an `IEnumerable.sort`. There is an `Array.Sort` but there is not an `IEnumerable.Sort`.